How can I cut a PCB in half and shift all traces, vias, components, shapes in Cadence Allegro PCB?
I'm fairly new to Cadence Allegro. I need to extend a board in the X direction.
How can I select everything in all layers (outline, traces, shapes, vias, components) and move/offset in the X direction?
